# Swift: UIScrollView & UIControl - addTarget | addGestureRecognizer - Not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, swift5, uicontrol

I am working with `UIScrollView` and `UIStackView` to scroll horizontally and select a `UIControl` element.

I have addTarget set on a `UIControl` element as follows inside a `UIStackView`:

i.e `HighlightColorView` is of type `UIControl`

```
lazy var colorsStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        stackView.alignment = .center
        stackView.spacing = 12
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        for color in colors {
            let colorView = HighlightColorView()
            colorView.backgroundColor = color
            colorView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleColorTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(colorView)
        }
        return stackView
    }()

@objc func handleColorTap(_ sender: UIView) {
        highlightSelectionDelegate.didTapColor(colorView: sender, mainView: self)
        let viewBackgroundColor = sender.backgroundColor ?? .black
        print("", viewBackgroundColor)
    }
```

The issue is that when you tap on a `colorView` which is of type `UIControl` the tap doesn't work as expected. There seems to be a freeze and it only works when the view is dismissed.

Basically you tap on a color and nothing happens then when you dismiss the view then the tap registers and starts working. 
It seems to be an issue with the scrollView but I am not sure.

Implementation of the `scrollView`:

```
lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scView = UIScrollView()
        scView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 12, bottom: 0, right: 12)
        scView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        scView.delaysContentTouches = false
        return scView
    }()
```

The use case it to be able to scroll on colors and tap them to highlight a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I noticed is that you may be referring to `UITapGestureRecognizer`. if you are using `UIGestureRecognizer` by itself then it won't work.

```swift
     let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleColorTap))
     view.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
```

To answer the question you asked

A `UIGestureRecognizer` is to be used with a single view. answer by @TomSwift.
 I think this applies in your case where you are using multiple views. set `addTarget` or `addGestureRecognizer` to only one view.

If you are using multiple view such as in your case where you have a `UIControl` inside a `UIStackView` and the `UIStackView` inside a `UIScrollView` you need to make sure that `addTarget` or `addGestureRecognizer` is only set to one of the `views` only.

Since you want the `UIControl` to respond to a tap you need to set `addTarget` only on this view and not on the `UIScrollView` and/or `UIStackView` .

```swift
for color in colors {
    let colorView = HighlightColorView()
    colorView.backgroundColor = color
    colorView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleColorTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    colorsStackView.addArrangedSubview(colorView)
  }
```

#### Note: You do not have to put the code inside a `viewDidLoad` function, It is fine where it is. Just remove additional `addTarget` or `addGestureRecognizer` from your views.